Trying to setup Apache Kafka on docker.desktop
I am trying to setup Apache Kafka on Docker Desktop but it is giving error when i try to run kafka server ...
Zookeeper is running perfectly and smoothly on docker desktop where i have installed and ran docker image for apache kafka...
But when i try to run kafka server it is giving me some command logs and then stops afterwards
command i am using to start kafka server is giving below
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties

logs it is giving are given below
[2024-12-26 13:49:55,074] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2024-12-26 13:49:56,408] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2024-12-26 13:49:59,149] INFO Registered signal handlers for TERM, INT, HUP (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2024-12-26 13:49:59,165] INFO [ControllerServer id=1] Starting controller (kafka.server.ControllerServer)
[2024-12-26 13:50:00,525] INFO Updated connection-accept-rate max connection creation rate to 2147483647 (kafka.network.ConnectionQuotas)
[2024-12-26 13:50:00,615] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=CONTROLLER, nodeId=1] Created data-plane acceptor and processors for endpoint : ListenerName(CONTROLLER) (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2024-12-26 13:50:00,651] INFO authorizerStart completed for endpoint CONTROLLER. Endpoint is now READY. (org.apache.kafka.server.network.EndpointReadyFutures)
[2024-12-26 13:50:00,657] INFO [SharedServer id=1] Starting SharedServer (kafka.server.SharedServer)
[2024-12-26 13:50:00,829] INFO [LogLoader partition=__cluster_metadata-0, dir=/tmp/kraft-combined-logs] Recovering unflushed segment 0. 0/1 recovered for __cluster_metadata-0. (kafka.log.LogLoader)
[2024-12-26 13:50:00,836] INFO [LogLoader partition=__cluster_metadata-0, dir=/tmp/kraft-combined-logs] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.UnifiedLog$)
[2024-12-26 13:50:00,842] INFO [LogLoader partition=__cluster_metadata-0, dir=/tmp/kraft-combined-logs] Reloading from producer snapshot and rebuilding producer state from offset 0 (kafka.log.UnifiedLog$)
[2024-12-26 13:50:00,844] INFO Deleted producer state snapshot /tmp/kraft-combined-logs/__cluster_metadata-0/00000000000000003539.snapshot (org.apache.kafka.storage.internals.log.SnapshotFile)
[2024-12-26 13:50:00,845] INFO [LogLoader partition=__cluster_metadata-0, dir=/tmp/kraft-combined-logs] Producer state recovery took 2ms for snapshot load and 1ms for segment recovery from offset 0 (kafka.log.UnifiedLog$)
[2024-12-26 13:50:01,094] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=__cluster_metadata-0] Wrote producer snapshot at offset 3860 with 0 producer ids in 12 ms. (org.apache.kafka.storage.internals.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2024-12-26 13:50:01,137] INFO [LogLoader partition=__cluster_metadata-0, dir=/tmp/kraft-combined-logs] Loading producer state till offset 3860 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.UnifiedLog$)
[2024-12-26 13:50:01,137] INFO [LogLoader partition=__cluster_metadata-0, dir=/tmp/kraft-combined-logs] Reloading from producer snapshot and rebuilding producer state from offset 3860 (kafka.log.UnifiedLog$)
[2024-12-26 13:50:01,139] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=__cluster_metadata-0] Loading producer state from snapshot file 'SnapshotFile(offset=3860, file=/tmp/kraft-combined-logs/__cluster_metadata-0/00000000000000003860.snapshot)' (org.apache.kafka.storage.internals.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2024-12-26 13:50:01,150] INFO [LogLoader partition=__cluster_metadata-0, dir=/tmp/kraft-combined-logs] Producer state recovery took 12ms for snapshot load and 0ms for segment recovery from offset 3860 (kafka.log.UnifiedLog$)
[2024-12-26 13:50:01,275] INFO Initialized snapshots with IDs SortedSet() from /tmp/kraft-combined-logs/__cluster_metadata-0 (kafka.raft.KafkaMetadataLog$)
[2024-12-26 13:50:01,323] INFO [raft-expiration-reaper]: Starting (kafka.raft.TimingWheelExpirationService$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2024-12-26 13:50:01,367] INFO [RaftManager id=1] Reading KRaft snapshot and log as part of the initialization (org.apache.kafka.raft.KafkaRaftClient)
[2024-12-26 13:50:01,501] INFO [RaftManager id=1] Starting voters are VoterSet(voters={1=VoterNode(voterKey=ReplicaKey(id=1, directoryId=Optional.empty), listeners=Endpoints(endpoints={ListenerName(CONTROLLER)=localhost/127.0.0.1:9093}), supportedKRaftVersion=SupportedVersionRange[min_version:0, max_version:0])}) (org.apache.kafka.raft.KafkaRaftClient)
[2024-12-26 13:50:01,505] INFO [RaftManager id=1] Starting request manager with static voters: [localhost:9093 (id: 1 rack: null)] (org.apache.kafka.raft.KafkaRaftClient)

